# Multithreading takes more time to execute in my c# program than sequential execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

My C# program does two jobs:

1. Read records from a file into a queue - one line per record
2. Read data from queue and do processing on the data.

The file has around 1 billion records. Each record is max 40 characters. Below sample code depicts how am I doing in multithreading way.

```cs
//File 1: MessageQueue.cs (Reads data from file into queue)
public class MessageQueue
{
    public Queue<string> logQueue = new Queue<string>();
    public bool fileread = false;
    string textFile = <file name with location>
    public void populateQueue()
{
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(textFile))
            {
                string ln;
                while (true)
                {
                    while (logQueue.Count < 1000000)
                    {
                        ln = file.ReadLine();
                        if(ln == null)
                        {
                            lock (logQueue)
                            {
                                fileread = true;
                            }
                            file.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                        lock (logQueue)
                        {
                            logQueue.Enqueue(ln);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (fileread)
                        break;
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            }
        }
}

//File 2: Processes data

   

     public class DoSomething
        {
            MessageQueue msgQueue;
    
        public DoSomething(MessageQueue msgQueue)
        {
        this.msgQueue = msgQueue;
        
        }
    
            public void ProcessData()
            {
                Queue<String> logsQueue = msgQueue.logQueue;
    
                while (true)
                {
                    string logMessage = "";
                    lock (logsQueue)
                    {
                        if (logsQueue.Count != 0)
                            logMessage = logsQueue.Dequeue();
    
                        else if (!msgQueue.fileread)
                            {
                                continue; //Queue is empty but there are still records in file
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break; //Whole file is read and queue is also empty
                            }
                    }
    //Do more processing with logMessage
            }

File 3: Main

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            MessageQueue msgQueue = new MessageQueue();
            DoSomething doSomething= new DoSomething(msgQueue);

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(msgQueue.populateQueue));
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doSomething.ProcessData));

            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Time spent in whole loop is " + endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds);

        }
```

My idea was to ensure that queue keeps on getting populated in one thread while other thread is processing the data from queue. The other way to do it is sequential where first reads the 1 million record in queue, then that data is processed and once queue is empty, read another 1 million record/process and continue in this way till whole file is not read. What it turns out that sequential way is faster than multithreading way. Am I doing something wrong in multithreading code?

Comment: We cant debug a story, there are lots of ways to make multithreading slower and do the wrong thing. Maybe you can create a small [mcve]

Comment: How does the consumer thread knowns when the `Queue<T>` contains enough data? Is it pooling the queue in a loop? Have you added any `Thread.Sleep` in the loop, or it's spinning non stop?

Comment: Also are you interested solely for an explanation about why your parallel implementation is slightly slower than the sequential implementation, or you are asking what's the best technique for processing this kind of workload with speed and efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First, you don't need to lock the collection when reading, or when setting a local flag. Second, I think you are overcomplicating things. Just load up a million records at a time, and process them in parallel, load another million, etc... The System.Collections.Concurrent namespace provides (as the name suggests) collections suitable for parallel execution. Each of these implement internal partitioning to avoid having to manage locks manually. But do you even need a Queue? System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel provides a .ForEach implementation to iterate through a collection in parallel. No locks or special collection required:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

...

```
        var batchSize = 1000000;
        using (var file = new StreamReader(@"C:\somefile.log"))
        {
            var done = false;

            while (!done)
            {
                var cnt = batchSize;
                var lines = new List<string>();

                while (cnt > 0)
                {
                    var line = file.ReadLine();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lines.Add(line);
                        cnt -= 1;
                    }                        
                }

                Parallel.ForEach(lines, 
                    line =>
                    {
                        ProcessLine(line);
                    });

                lines.Clear();
                lines = null;
            }

            file.Close();
        }
```

And, of course, you can launch that whole thing asynchronously using a Thread or a Task.

Note however that you cannot guarantee the order in which the items will be processed using parallel processing like this. If the order in which the records are processed is important, then you will need to instead partition your billion records into a practical amount of records (divide the number of records by Environment.ProcessorCount - 1) you can then process in separate threads and then recombine in order.

Answer (score -1):

Reading 1 million records into a queue sounds like it will be memory intensive. I can imagine you are using a lot text operations too which is also memory intensive and would make the Garbage collector and CPU quite busy.

I would suggest a dedicated thread to read the file as fast as it can, but perhaps limiting it to something practical like 1000 records at a time. Then a separate thread pool or Paralel.For loop with MaxDegreeOfParallelism configured to play around with the total threads to be used to process the line entries.

As your threads have processed the data they should signal the file reader to get more records from the file to be processed.

The bottom line is that a billion lines is a lot of data and records. You need to break it down in small chunks to process it efficiently.

**Quick and Dirty solution yet effective.**
If you don't need to process the lines in sequence then you could put a whole separate app as step 1, that splits the massive file into several files of 1mil lines (make it configurable) each in size. This then drops it into another folder where your original app just picks it up and processes it. You could even spin up multiple instances of your original app to handle files concurrently.

Comment: The *Quick and Dirty* characterization is probably unsuitable, because an efficient multithreading solution can be implemented in 10 minutes with less than 10 lines of code, if you know what you are doing. It's hard to beat that by splitting data in multiples files and spawning multiple processes. *Low tech and Dirty* is more to the point IMHO. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it's true that multithreading will be more efficient. I added the quick and dirty as a simple solution for developers that are still new to coding instead of just throwing them into the deep end.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey reading the file is not the issue. It's allocating resources to the code he wants to execute with each lines data. 1 billion records is a lot of data. For example have you every worked on a database containing that many records? Processing code routines with each and every row would take long and consume a lot of time and system resources if not done correctly.

Comment: I forgot to remove this comment the other day, I originally mistakenly thought it was 1 million records... I edited the code in my answer to read and process records 1 million at a time, but didn't remove this comment.